# Does the ORDER BY clause return a Virtual Table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, order-of-execution

My understanding is that relational tables aren't ordered.

I also understand that each step, or phase, of the query execution returns a "virtual table" which is passed as input to the next phase.

But if tables are never actually ordered, what's happening during/after the ORDER BY phase?

I'm just trying to understand what might happen with a query like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2 
FROM mytable 
ORDER BY col1 
LIMIT 1;
```

Edit:

To clarify. I know what the query above outputs. I'm trying to better understand each phase/step of the underlying execution.

The (logical) order of execution (EDIT: different from the physical execution) for the above query would be:

```
FROM 
SELECT
ORDER BY 
LIMIT
```

I'm trying to understand what's going on during the `ORDER BY` phase. My understanding is that a virtual table is passed from the `SELECT` phase to the `ORDER BY` phase (in this case, a table with `col1` and `col2`, but I don't know what's being returned by `ORDER BY` and subsequently passed to `LIMIT`.

Comment: Do `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT col1, col2  FROM mytable  ORDER BY col1 LIMIT 1;` to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks. Not quite what I'm looking for though. I'm more looking to see what happens at each stage, rather than the steps taken during the physical execution. For example, the FROM clause generates a virtual table and passes this as input to the SELECT clause, which then passes a virtual table to the ORDER BY clause. But I don't think the ORDER BY clause actually generates a table

Comment: Then read [Query execution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/overview.html). Pretty sure you will find things do not work the way you think they do and that `EXPLAIN` is the best way to see what actually happens.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the ORDER BY clause return a Virtual Table?

Sometimes.

The database engine tries as much as it can not to produce a *materialized result set* (that you call virtual table). Most of the time it's more efficient to work the rows one by one, so they can be successively processed by each execution step until they are returned to the client app.

However, this is not always possible. In such cases, the engine is forced to materialize an intermediate result that actually takes the form you are thinking about. But again, this is expensive, and is usually avoided.

> The (logical) order of execution for the above query would be:
> FROM
> SELECT
> ORDER BY
> LIMIT

No. This is just how a SQL query is written and is unrelated to the actual execution steps. Take that sequence as a good pedagogical tool, useful [for learning purposes only] to understand how the result is produced. Behind the scenes, the engine cheats in all kinds of ways to do as less effort as possible to produce the result you asked. You wouldn't believe it if you saw it.

Comment: Ok thanks. For the second part, I agree with you, it's just my wording may be off. I added the word `logical` to separate it form the actual, `physical` execution, as it's the `logical` order I'm trying to wrap my head around at the moment. Should note that most my knowledge here is taken from the first chapter of `T-SQL Querying`. For the `ORDER BY` section it talks about returning a `cursor` (not quite sure what this is yet) rather than a `materialised` result. When you talk about working with rows one by one, is this related to the idea of a `cursor`? (Sorry if my questions are dumb)

Comment: @TheDataPanda Yes, I put it in simple words, but "working with rows one by one" means the same as "cursor". The technical term is "pipelining", as opposed to "materializing". Most of the time the former is cheaper than the latter.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying table is not sorted when you use ORDER BY, only the results returned by the SELECT statement are. That query will return the first result from `mytable`. Since the default order is ASCENDING, it will be the lowest value in `col1`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just to understand each step of the execution. From my understanding, the virtual tables returned by each step are still relational tables. So I'm not sure what's been passed from the ORDER BY clause to the LIMIT clause.

Answer (score 0):

the order is in tables unknown, and by definition unsorted

a result set as the end product of a SELECT without an `ORDER BY`is also unsorted.

but as the `ORDER BY` is the penultimate command before LIMIT and OFFSET , the result set is in that specific order